# Cordova iOS & Android widget

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

We are developing an application using Cordova.
We need to make a widget (iOS, Android) with the possibility of background synchronization with API and displaying data in the widget.
I googled a bit and found only Microsoft Ace technology.

- http://microsoft.github.io/ace/

But it has been unsupported for a long time. And it doesn't work with Cordova 9+ versions.
What other solutions or technologies are there for widget development with Cordova ?